# Cannot call any method outside my controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

**Situation:**

- Using Spring MVC I prompt a user in my view to enter some information into the form.
- I bind that information to a form object (like normal).
- I successfully get data back to my controller (confirmed) via log dump.

**The Problem:**

- Now I'm in the controller with all the data the user entered into the form (bound to a form object).
- I take that same object with data in it and I try to pass it to my service class method to use the data in a way I need it to.

The problem is that as soon (as soon) as my controller calls the service method it throws an exception.  It doesn't even reach a 'log.info' (which is the first line of code in that method).

This should absolutely be working and I'm very taken back as to why it isn't.  It seems like a very simple matter.  i.e.(get the data back to my controller;  use that data in a call to a service method).

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerAccount(@ModelAttribute User user, Locale locale,
Model model) {
    String theView = "";
    try{
        logger.info("User submitted Registration Form");

        user.setPaidStatus("ACTIVE");
        user.setUserRole("SUBSCRIBER");
        logger.info(user.toString());  //Proving all the data is available.

        userService.createNewUser(user); //This is the call to my service 
     //method.  As soon as it reaches it it exceptions out right away.          
        //userDao.createNewUser(userDto); //just to see if it does the same 
                                          //thing elsewhere - (it does)

        model.addAttribute("command", new User());
        theView = "login";

    } catch(SaveMyFavsException se){
        logger.info(se.getCmdCode() + ", Message: " + se.getCmdMsg());
        model.addAttribute("command", new User());
        model.addAttribute("error", se.getCmdCode() + ", Message: " + 
se.getCmdMsg());
        return "register";
    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        model.addAttribute("command", new User());
        model.addAttribute("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return "register";
    }

    return theView;
}
```

**SERVICE CLASS (See createNewUser())**

```
@Component
public class UserService implements UserServiceInterface{

    @Autowired
    UserDaoInterface userDao;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);


    public void createNewUser(User user){
        int result = 0;
        try{
            //FAILS BEFORE MAKING IT HERE (automatically ends up in the second Catch block for Exception with no message)
            logger.info("Entered createNewUser() service");     
            logger.info("User ID: " + user.getUserId());    
            result = userDao.createNewUser(user);                                                   
            logger.info("New User DAO Complete - Rows Inserted: " + result);

        } catch(SaveMyFavsException se){
            throw new SaveMyFavsException(se.getCmdCode(), se.getCmdMsg());

        } catch(Exception e){
            logger.info("General Exception occurred during service to create new user...  Trace: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new SaveMyFavsException(2000015, "General Exception occurred during service to create new user...  Trace: " + e.getLocalizedMessage()); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Please be as detailed as possible in your question** like telling us what the Exception is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: If you are looking at my post - the User object has multiple properties:

- userId
- firstName
- lastName
- etc....

All of them are populated (except for the date properties I have in there), which aren't meant to be populated here.  They are used for data extraction from the database.  I tried removing them and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Apply the text of exception

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the full error message because you're eating the full stack trace. Change your logger to:
            logger.info("General Exception occurred during service to create new user.", e);

Comment: How am I eating the full stack trace?  e.getLocalizedMessage() is a value passed to the logger.  There is no message as far as I can tell.  Let me check it out again.  If that is the case, I'll dump it out.

Comment: I just re-checked it and if there was a message it would definitely be displayed.  Can you elaborate on your post?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code which inject the userService to the controller. This seems to be an issue with the bean injection.

Comment: Below I have included it...  The DI is working - because I'm getting the error message 'from' the service class meaning it is accessing the method.  Maybe I'm not thinking of something you could shed some light on.

 <bean id="userService"  class="com.savemyfavs.service.UserService"></bean>


 @Autowired
 UserServiceInterface userService;

Comment: Below I have included it...  The DI is working - because I'm getting the error message 'from' the service class meaning it is accessing the method.  Maybe I'm not thinking of something you could shed some light on.

(
 <bean id="userService"  class="com.savemyfavs.service.UserService"></bean>


 @Autowired
 UserServiceInterface userService;
)